# How to keep first option selected in oi-select angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-select

[Plunker to try](http://plnkr.co/edit/mwNkSCBCrz3zXXbdJK8o?p=preview) I am using oi-select library to select multiple options, I want the first value from data should be selected by default, as soon as the data is available.
html code

```
<oi-select multiple ng-init="selectedNewRelease=releaseList[0]" 
oi-options="item.releaseId for item in releaseList" ng-model="selectedNewRelease" 
placeholder="Select Releases" 
oi-select-options="{dropdownFilter: 'myDropdownFilter'}" id="selectedReleases" 
ng-change="onReleaseChange();toggleCol();"></oi-select>
```

I tried with ng-init, by assigning as below :

```
 $scope.selectedNewRelease=$scope.releaseList[0];
```

This actually works but as soon as I select one or more option it removes default selected option. Any idea any link please. link for [oi-select](https://tamtakoe.github.io/oi.select/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when setting default value for `oi-select`(multiple) with a Object not Array, selecting new item will lead to overwriting the original value.
So you should init it with an `Array`.Something like this:

```
ng-init="selectedNewRelease=[releaseList[0]]
```

refer this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0YRiCeEjYRW6HL6rrCfj?p=preview).

---

**UPDATE:**

`oi-select` used `ngModel` to achieve `two-way-databinding`, and since angular won't trigger change if the `instance` of the array is not changed(means ng-change won't fire without instance changed).

So after push new items, you should do something like this:

```
$scope.selectedNewRelease = $scope.selectedNewRelease.slice(); // create new instance for the array.
```

Comment: yeah I tried pushing first record to $scope.selectedNewReleases.push(releaseList[0]), but its not showing selected, when I select second value it shows first and second then.

Comment: @Sudarshan when did you push the first item? if in async callbacks, maybe you should consider invoke `$scope.$apply`.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/mwNkSCBCrz3zXXbdJK8o?p=preview this is my real time fiddle. I tried scope.apply too check here

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/63IL5lZ7hAoNqvtAlqWk?p=preview this works with first option selection but when I select second option first option goes away.

Comment: @Sudarshan In your first plunker, you won't get the real data for `query` will return as `promise`. And the second plunker, please remove the `ng-init`.

Comment: yeah its working in plunker here thanks for that, but in my project its not working at all. :-(

Comment: @Sudarshan The difference between these two is how you do with the data. Maybe you should post code about that or maybe post a new question.

Comment: both the cases are fine and both are same as I am doing and both working in plunker but in my project dont know whats going wrong, I am trying by push also as well as ng-init also one after other\

Comment: @Sudarshan sorry for that. Let me know if there anything can help.

Comment: I have three dropdows like this this, so on selection of second I am making call to get data and after data I need this pre-selection. Yeah thanks Pengy anyhow I will accept your answer. I have to see wats wrong I am doing :-(

Comment: @Sudarshan I have update the answer with some new things and also the plunker. Go check it, I think this will help.

Comment: great thinking use of slice, new instance will keep in mind, next time.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`ng-init="selectedNewRelease=releaseList[0]"`  instead of `ng-init="releaseList[0]"`

Edit:

Or remove `ng-init="selectedNewRelease=releaseList[0]"`  on oi-select and assign the value in controller after load the `releaseList` data

like

```
function controller($scope)
{
Loaddropdown()
{
$http().success(function(data){
$scope.releaseList = data;
$scope.selectedNewRelease =$scope.releaseList[0]//or $scope.selectedNewRelease=$scope.releaseList[0].Id// which id means what's your value  
})
}
}
```

Comment: Yeah I have tried that sorry by mistake I forgot to edit correct way, but no luck, seems like oi-select wont support ng-init only

Comment: I tried this too, I have mentioned in my question please see, it works but when I select any other option then selected value goes away. Please read my question, also i cant assign from my controller, because I need selectedNewReleases to iterate to see how many options are selected. if i assign then its lenght will be always 0 on each call.

Comment: ` it works but when I select any other option then selected value goes away` That is the dropdown functional. right?

Comment: Its a oi-select, which has multiple selection option please refer link for oi-select OI have given , for example see this http://plnkr.co/edit/0YRiCeEjYRW6HL6rrCfj?p=preview

Comment: Plesae  add  `multiple` attribute in the `oi-select`. Check it https://tamtakoe.github.io/oi.select/#/select/#multiple

Comment: This is my real time fiddle please try here http://plnkr.co/edit/mwNkSCBCrz3zXXbdJK8o?p=preview